# How to change or modify date column value in another format using HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have table having a date column.

Earlier i have inserted date value as in the format '7/8/2012'. - m/d/yyyy
I want to change this format in the form of '07/08/2014'. - mm/dd/yyyy

I have around 3000 entries in my table. How to alter this date value into new format.
I tried to use "alter" command with set, but unable to change this in a bulk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern) UDF .

Let this current table be a dummy table. Then create a new final table with the same schema. and then insert into this new table with the below command:

```
insert overwrite table table_name select coulmn1,column2,unix_timestamp(dateCOLUMN, string pattern) from old table.
```

You can define any date pattern you need.

refer : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions